# Garbled text when constructing emails with vmime

Tags: c++, qt, text, encode, vmime

Hey, my Qt C++ program has a part where it needs to send the first 128 characters or so of the output of a bash command to an email address. The output from the tty is captured in a text box in my gui called textEdit_displayOutput and put into my message I built using the Message Builder ( the object m_vmMessage ) Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
m_vmMessage.getTextPart()->setCharset( vmime::charsets::US_ASCII );
m_vmMessage.getTextPart()->setText( vmime::create < vmime::stringContentHandler > ( ui->textEdit_displayOutput->toPlainText().toStdString() ) );
vmime::ref < vmime::message > msg = m_vmMessage.construct();
vmime::utility::outputStreamAdapter out( std::cout );
msg->generate( out );
```

Giving bash 'ls /' and a newline makes vmime give terminal output like this:

```
ls /=0Abin    etc=09   initrd.img.old  mnt=09 sbin=09  tmp=09   vmlinuz.o=
ld=0Aboot   farts=09   lib=09=09   opt=09 selinux  usr=0Acdrom  home=09  =
 lost+found=09   proc  srv=09  var=0Adev    initrd.img  media=09   root  =
```

Whereas it should look more like this:

```
ls /
bin    etc     initrd.img.old  mnt   sbin     tmp      vmlinuz.old
boot   farts       lib         opt   selinux  usr
cdrom  home    lost+found      proc  srv      var
dev    initrd.img  media       root  sys      vmlinuz
18:22>
```

Output seems to be truncated around 'root', nothing after it is displayed.

How do I encode and piece together the email properly? Does vmime just display it like that on purpose and the actual content of the email is complete and properly formatted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`=0A` is a line feed (LF) character.
`=09` is a horizontal tab (HT).

I think this is just MIME's way of encoding your non-printing (control) characters.

Comment: Ok, so the actual information in the email is fine?
Not only that, but it's also not giving the whole output of `ls` ( Notice it's truncated at 'root' )

Comment: What do you see on the receiving of the email? A decent email client shouldn't show you the raw MIME-encoded attachment, I would think. Also, the truncation thing is possibly a separate problem. Is there a buffered output stream that you're not flushing, or...?